# using pthreads in fortran

Tags: module, pthreads, fortran, libraries

i want to use pthreads in my fortran program but i cannot even get it to compile. i have used pthreads in C programs and need it for my fortran program but a call to `use f_pthread` results in the following error:

`Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'f_pthread.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory`

so quite obviously i don't have f_pthread.mod linking. where is f_pthread.mod and/or how do i go about making it or downloading it? every single thing i have looked up talks about how to use pthreads in fortran, with a 'use f_pthread' at the beginning of the example program, but i cannot seem to figure out how they correctly link that module.

Answer (score 4):

I've only ever come across the module `f_pthread` on IBM/AIX installations.  If you have such an installation then the extensive IBM documentation should point you towards it.  If you don't have, what makes you think you have that module ?  Where does your compiler on your platform (you tell us neither) put module files ?  Have you looked for `f_pthread.mod` there ?

Why do you 'need' pthreads for your Fortran program ?  It would be much easier to use OpenMP, and there are only a few things that pthreads can do that OpenMP can't and which most Fortran programs are likely to want to do.

Comment: i "need" openmp because it is much easier to create a threadpool in pthreads. i have a small (~800) for loop which is evaulated thousands upon thousands of times. i would like to thread this because using openmp might start up new threads each time i call the loop and this would be inefficient.

Comment: You might want to just trust your OpenMP implementation at this point; in practice, current OpenMP implementations do create a threadpool and reuse it rather than constantly creating and deleting threads.  Then you end up with a program that is standards compliant and should work with pretty much any Fortran compiler anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanDursi and HighPerformanceMark, what if a fortran program requires two separate functional threads for separate tasks, not just parallelization?

Comment: @patrickvacek - best to ask that as a new question and provide a few more details.